# All UITextFields in TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have had some problems with checking if all `UITextFields` where filled in in my UITableView with Custom `UITableViewCell classes`

I was trying to do something with this sort of code:

```
for (UITextField* textField in self.view.subviews ){
NSLog(@"Text: %@", textField.text);
}
```

And this is the error:

```
-[UITableView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b034400
```

Oke, so I seem to be trying to get the UITableView say its text value, so that is not good. But how can I get the TableViewCell's TextFields? So I can check if the user filled in everything and it can save the information.

Grz

Comment: This probable isn't going to work as it won't 'see' textfields that are not on screen as they aren't drawn into the view hierarchy. You're better off validating against your data source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get reference to UITableViewCell and do the enumeration on cell.contentView, all controls are stored on contentView cell property, not view directly. All course you should do check if the view is type of UITextField if you have some other controls than UITextField on cell.

The other thing is that you are not able to get UITextField reference for the cell which are not visible because they will be most likely dequeued.

This gives  you all visible table view cells and you just need to enumerate it:

```
NSArray *arr =  [self.tableView visibleCells];
for (UITableViewCell *cell in arr)  {
    for (UIView *v in cell.contentView.subviews) {

        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) v;
            NSLog(@"Text: %@", textField.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

that because view's subviews are not necessarily UITextField objects, try this:

```
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews //be sure you are looping through the right view){
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) subview;
            NSLog(@"Text: %@", textField.text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if it is in iOS 7, Your textfields should be in the first view in Cell's subviews

`for (UITextField* textField in self.view.subviews[0] ){
     NSLog(@"Text: %@", textField.text);
}`